# Divide two columns in pivot table and plot grouped bar chart with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, group-by, pivot-table

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Vintage': ['2016Q1','2016Q1', '2016Q2','2016Q3','2016Q4','2016Q1', '2016Q2','2016Q2','2016Q2','2016Q3','2016Q4'], 
     'Model': ['A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B',],
     'Count': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
     'Case':[0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0],
    })

Vintage Model   Count   Case
0   2016Q1  A   1   0
1   2016Q1  A   1   1
2   2016Q2  A   1   1
3   2016Q3  A   1   0
4   2016Q4  A   1   1
5   2016Q1  B   1   1
6   2016Q2  B   1   0
7   2016Q2  B   1   0
8   2016Q2  B   1   1
9   2016Q3  B   1   1
10  2016Q4  B   1   0
```

What I need to do is:

1. Plot grouped bar chart, where `vintage` is the groups and `model` is the hue/color
2. Two line plots in the same chart that show the percentage of `case` over `count`, aka plot the division of case over count for each model and vintage.

I figured out how to do the first task with a pivot table but haven't been able to add the percentage from the same pivot.

This is the solution for point 1:

```
dfp = df.pivot_table(index='vintage', columns='model', values='count', aggfunc='sum')
dfp.plot(kind='bar', figsize=(8, 4), rot=45,  ylabel='Frequency', title="Vintages")
```

[image]

I tried dividing between columns in the pivot table but it's not the right format to plot.

How can I do the percentage calculation and line plots so without creating a different table?

Could the whole task be done with `groupby` instead? (as I find it easier to use in general)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using the seaborn plotting library, not sure if it's ok for you to use it for your problem

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Vintage': ['2016Q1','2016Q1', '2016Q2','2016Q3','2016Q4','2016Q1', '2016Q2','2016Q2','2016Q2','2016Q3','2016Q4'], 
    'Model': ['A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B',],
    'Count': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
    'Case':[0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0],
})

agg_df = df.groupby(['Vintage','Model']).sum().reset_index()
agg_df['Fraction'] = agg_df['Case']/agg_df['Count']

sns.barplot(
    x = 'Vintage',
    y = 'Count',
    hue = 'Model',
    alpha = 0.5,
    data = agg_df,
)
sns.lineplot(
    x = 'Vintage',
    y = 'Fraction',
    hue = 'Model',
    marker = 'o',
    legend = False,
    data = agg_df,
)
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you want the lines to be drawn on the same plot. I'd recommend creating a new y-axis after computing the division from the original df. Then you can plot the lines with seaborn:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Vintage': ['2016Q1','2016Q1', '2016Q2','2016Q3','2016Q4','2016Q1', '2016Q2','2016Q2','2016Q2','2016Q3','2016Q4'], 
     'Model': ['A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B',],
     'Count': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
     'Case':[0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0],
    })

dfp = df.pivot_table(index='Vintage', columns='Model', values='Count', aggfunc='sum')
ax1 = dfp.plot(kind='bar', figsize=(8, 4), rot=45,  ylabel='Frequency', title="Vintages")

dfd = df.groupby(["Vintage", "Model"]).sum() \
        .assign(div_pct=lambda x:100*x["Case"]/x["Count"]) \
        .reset_index()

ax2 = ax1.twinx() # creating a second y axis
sns.lineplot(data=dfd, x="Vintage", y="div_pct", hue="Model", style="Model", ax=ax2, markers=True, dashes=False)

plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]